# LINQ OrderBy query fails to sort properly by descending dateTime

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sorting, datetime

I have a simple linq query which sorts the records based on dateTime both descending and ascending. for some reason it's failing at 13:00:00 hrs.

```
sortedrecords = sortedrecords.OrderByDescending(x => x.DateTime).ThenBy(x=>x.Time);
```

it's supposed to sort 2PM, 1PM, 12PM. But 1 PM records come at very end.

Is there something wrong with my query? Any suggestions will help.

Thanks

Order by descending (Failure)

10/12/2017 2:00:56 PM
10/12/2017 2:00:50 PM
10/12/2017 12:29:41 PM
10/12/2017 12:28:32 PM
10/12/2017 12:27:35 PM
10/12/2017 11:21:35 AM
10/12/2017 11:14:16 AM
10/12/2017 1:49:28 PM
10/12/2017 1:43:23 PM

Order by ascending (correct)

10/12/2017 12:27:35 PM
10/12/2017 12:28:32 PM
10/12/2017 12:29:41 PM
10/12/2017 1:43:23 PM
10/12/2017 1:49:28 PM
10/12/2017 2:00:50 PM
10/12/2017 2:00:56 PM

Comment: What are your `x.DateTime` and `x.Time` properties? Please show what the `sortedrecords` object's class look like.

Comment: Try `OrderByDescending(x => x.DateTime.Date).ThenBy(x=>x.Time);`

Comment: @sach DateTime property looks like this 10/12/2017 12:23:28 PM. and i even tried this sortedrecords = sortedrecords.OrderByDescending(x => x.DateTime);

Comment: That's not what I meant. The `DateTime` .NET struct doesn't have a `Time` property, so obviously this list is something you defined yourself. Show us what it looks like.

Comment: Actually, you should check the `DateTime.Ticks` property. Are you using DateTime with different TimeZone specifications? If no timezone is involved then an easy workaround would be to use `DateTime.Ticks` to sort

Comment: @jimRhodes yes it is string!

Comment: Are your date and time values strings? If so, you will want to use 24 hour clock and zero-pad to 2 digits

Comment: @SantoshKumar without partially answering questions here I suggest you edit your original post to show what the `sortedrecords` object's class looks like.

Comment: `yes it is string` <= Why are they strings? Keep them as type `DateTime` as long as possible. It only needs to be a string at the point it is presented to the user (like in a form or web page). I hope they are not also persisted in the data store as string....

Comment: A dataTime object is a double number with the integer portion the count of days from 1/1/1, and the fraction the fraction portion of the day like 6:00AM = .25.  Where did you ever learn that a DateTime is an integer?  You just need to sort by date and get rid of the time sort.

Comment: @jdweng The [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/System/datetime.cs) shows that `DateTime` is stored internally as an integer (`UInt64` specifically), see the code comments starting on line 130.

Comment: So it is a long instead of a double.  What I said is still accurate as long as you put the decimal point in the correct place.  it is in nano second so one day equal 0x3B9ACA00 which is the fractional part (32 bits).  So one day = 0x100000000.  When the fraction reaches 0x3B9aC9FF the next nanosecond is 0x1000000000.

Comment: Please show examples of your `DateTime` and `Time` values. If they're strings, show them as strings (with quotes around them). If they're scalar values, tell us what type they are (i.e. `double`, `long`, etc.). So far, what you're describing isn't making sense.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't specific your object types, your column types, your database (assuming you are using one), why you used a .Net class type name as a column name, etc. I will assume you are handling anonymous objects in a `List`:

```
sortedrecords = sortedrecords.OrderByDescending(x => DataTime.Parse(x.DateTime));
```